# Need help to rebuild the functions of the buttons, assign variable in c#

Tags: c#, button, ocr

I am trying to build a small .pdf -> .txt / searchable .pdf converter, but I am having trouble to assign the first var result to the other buttons

Made myself a "solution" but the code seems too messed and exagerated.

```
using IronOcr;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ocr
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;

                var Ocr = new IronTesseract(); // nothing to configure
                IronOcr.License.LicenseKey = "SOMELICENSEKEY";
                using (var Input = new OcrInput())
                {
                    Input.AddPdf(ofd.FileName, "password");
                    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
                    Console.WriteLine(Result.Text);

                    richTextBox1.Text = Result.Text;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;

                var Ocr = new IronTesseract(); // nothing to configure
                IronOcr.License.LicenseKey = "SOMELICENSEKEY";
                using (var Input = new OcrInput())
                {
                    Input.AddPdf(ofd.FileName, "password");
                    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
                    Console.WriteLine(Result.Text);
                    Result.SaveAsTextFile("pdf.txt");
                }
            }
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;

                var Ocr = new IronTesseract(); // nothing to configure
                IronOcr.License.LicenseKey = "SOMELICENSEKEY";
                using (var Input = new OcrInput())
                {
                    Input.AddPdf(ofd.FileName, "password");
                    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
                    Console.WriteLine(Result.Text);
                    Result.SaveAsSearchablePdf("pdfpesquisavel.pdf");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried to assign and use the variable "Result" in the others buttons fuctions (button 2 and button 3)

But it didn't worked.

Comment: Search about variable scopes. Result is declared inside the block, so only the block can access it. Declare it at class level instead.

Comment: Tried to search and learn about the variables scopes, class level variable.
Sadly, I was unsuccessful with my studies. Can you show me a example how it would work in my case?

Comment: Variables exists only inside the inner most `{ }` and its children. As I said previous, you have to declare your variable in your class, outside any methods.